# Display progress in a long loop in Unity3d

Tags: loops, unity-game-engine, progress-bar, coroutine

I'm building a space game, populated by thousands of star systems. Right now, there is a function that generates these thousands of systems. It takes about 5-10 seconds to generate, and I would like to have a simple progress bar updating the user in the progress.

After some searching I've decided to use a coroutine, however there is a little problem: when I call the function to generate star systems, the code that called the function keeps on going, reporting zero stars (because they haven't been generated yet).

I have a feeling coroutines are not an answer for me. Basically, I am simply looking for a way to simulate Application.DoEvents to update the GUI.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
// Start generating thousands of systems
StartCoroutine(GalacticMap.GenerateRandomGalaxy());
// after the universe is generated...
Game.myGalaxy.StarSystems = GalacticMap.myGalaxy.StarSystems;
// report back the number of systems
print(String.Format("Generated {0} systems", Game.myGalaxy.StarSystems.Count));
```

In the `GalacticMap.GenerateRandomGalaxy()` I am yielding back like this `yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);` however, the effect is not what I am looking for: execution goes right through to `print` statement while the generation is still on going.

So how do I do this?

## EDIT 1:

I've cooked up  a sample code to illustrate my issue.

The caller code:

```
Debug.Log ("Start generating");
StartCoroutine(GenerateMeGalaxy());
Debug.Log ("Finish generating");
```

The code I call:

```
public static IEnumerator  GenerateMeGalaxy ()
{
    Debug.Log ("GenerateMeGalaxy start");
    int numberOfStars = 1000;

    for (int i=0;i<=numberOfStars;i++)
    {
        // generate galaxy

        // display progress bar on screen
        Debug.Monitor(String.Format("{0}% completed", ((i*100)/numberOfStars)),2);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.001f);
    }
    Debug.Log ("GenerateMeGalaxy end");
}
```

In the code above, `Debug.Log` displays string on the screen, on a new line so you can read previous logged strings of whatever. This is to debug code execution. `Debug.Monitor` has a fixed location on the screen and will overwrite previous string. This is where I display progress percentage. What I see after running this code is:

```
Start generating
GenerateMeGalaxy start
Finish generating
GenerateMeGalaxy end
```

What I want to see is:

```
Start generating
GenerateMeGalaxy start
GenerateMeGalaxy end
Finish generating
```

... and also the progress update is happening in between:

```
GenerateMeGalaxy start
Finish generating
```

Comment: not very clear what you problem is. Can you refine it?

Comment: High level: I am calling a function to generate a large number of star systems. The function takes about 5-10 seconds to execute with 1000 stars. I have a progress displaying how much of generation is done notifying the user. The issue is, when I call that function, I don't see the progress changing like 5%...10%...15%... etc. Everything on screen freezes for 510 seconds, and then I just see 100% when the function is finished. In VB6, the issue would be solved very easily... put DoEvents after updating progress bar. Unity does not have this command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how Unity coroutines work. What the `yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f)` is essentially saying is "go do other stuff and come back to me after 0.1 second". So naturally Unity will go ahead and do other stuff, including the print statement.

What you want is something along the lines of the following pattern:

```
IEnumerator GenerateRandomGalaxy()
{
    int numSystems = 5000; // however many systems you want to generate
    foreach(int i = 0; i < numSystems; i++) 
    {
        // insert code here that generates system i

        // insert code here that updates the progress bar

        yield return null;
    }
    // put logic that prints out final number of systems generated here
}
```

What this does is generate a system, update the status bar, and then -- with the `yield return null` statement -- tell Unity to take over (so that it do other stuff, including rendering the updated progress bar) and come back and continue the loop as soon as possible.

Finally, the print statement only happens after the loop is finished, as you intend.

Comment: This method does not update the GUI part (the progress bar). Basically Everything on screen freezes and pops up as 100% after the routine finished

Comment: @George - you need to add logic to update the progress bar, as indicated. Hard for me to be more specific without seeing all your code.

Comment: The logic to update the progress is there and I can see it doing the increment (in my original code). The problem is that while its doing the increment the original code that called the function passed execution already without waiting for the function to finish. I will see if I can whip up a simple example and will update my OP

Comment: @George - the reason "Finish generating" is printing immediately is the reason I stated in my answer. You need to move that to the "put logic that prints out final number of systems generated here" location, otherwise it will print as soon as the coroutine yields the first time.

Comment: @George - not sure why you are doing yield return with a wait for a tiny amount of time. Shouldn't make a difference, since the amount of time is almost certainly less than a frame, but really you should do yield return null, which tells Unity to yield control until the next frame.

Comment: @George - again, I think you aren't quite understanding how coroutines are supposed to work. "The original code that called the function passed execution without waiting for the function to finish" is the POINT of a coroutine. That's what yield means. It means the the coroutine "yields" control.

Comment: @George - thus, in order to have something happen in order, i.e. after the coroutine is done with its work, you have to put that something inside the coroutine, since the work inside the coroutine will be done in order.

Comment: @ Ghopper21 - I suspected thats the case. Hence my "I have a feeling coroutines are not an answer for me" message. Again, do not concentrate on coroutines, it was something that someone suggested. My ultimate goal is to have progress displayed on screen while a long loop is being executed. In VB it was simple: `DoEvents`. I do not understand why such a simple thing is so overly complicated in Unity.

Comment: @George - I'm not saying it's wrong to use coroutines. This is a quite natural and appropriate use of coroutines. Anyhow, good luck!

Comment: Errrm, its still not working properly...I don't think coroutines will work here, but if you think it will, can you please show how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73545/discussion-between-ghopper21-and-george).